# Problem with fetching/getting data from server TO client. (Send data from client TO server is working sucessfully)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, server

I'm doing a project for the Udacity Front End Developer program. Purpose is to use API, node.js and webpack (build tools). In my website I've got a form where you are supposed to put in the url of an article and the client will send that url to the server, and then the server will send this to Aylien API which uses AI to analyze the text and return which category the text has etc.

So, I build the project in the terminal with npm run build-prod, and then run the server and start the website. I put in the url of an random trump article, and I can see the in the server terminal that the URL is sent TO server FROM client sucessfully (I've used console.log to control it), and then also sent to the external API sucessfully and returns the data (which category etc.) BUT, I then want to send that information/Data to the client but that's where I can't get it done. I've tried fixing it but can't see why I dont get the data to the client,and there's no error when using inspect in Google Chrome.

Can you guys help me out? Appreciate it!
Code below from the server js file and the client js file.

EDIT: Latest update on the code below:
EDIT 2: Problem now solved. Jacob helped me a lot. The issue was in me using a form, and not usin the preventDefault. Using a simple e.preventDefault helped with the issue.

Server js file:

```
    app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    console.log('I got a request.')
    const data = req.body;
    console.log(data);
    textapi.classify({
        url: data.text
    }, function(error, response) {
        if (error === null) {
            console.log(response);
            res.json(response);
            res.end();
        } else {
            console.log('This is not a valid text or article to evaluate. Try again.')
        }
    });
});
```

Client js file:

```
    async function postData (url, data) {
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
}

formBox.addEventListener('submit', () => {
    data.text = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
    postData('/post', data);
});
```

Comment: You need to put the `res.send` _inside of the callback for `textapi.classify`_. Otherwise you're calling `res.send` before that finishes.

Comment: @Jacob, thanks for answering. That didn't work tho. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You also need to _end_ the response. Added to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most JavaScript callbacks, including the one for `textapi.classify` are called *asynchronously*. Anything you want to happen after that asynchronous code finishes *also* has to go in that callback.

```
app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;
  textapi.classify({
    url: data.text
  }, function(error, response) {
    if (error === null) {
      res.end(response);
    } else {
      res.status(400).end('This is not a valid text or article to evaluate. Try again.');
    }
  });
});
```

Notice that I also changed `res.send` to `res.end`, which both sends a chunk of data and ends the response. If you don't do that, then node thinks you're not yet done sending chunks back to the client.

If you want to make your code less nested with callbacks, you can use async functions (Promises). For APIs that don't return Promises, you can use `require('util').promisify` to wrap them. Here's how you'd use an async function approach:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

const classifyText = promisify(textapi.classify.bind(textapi));

app.post('/post', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await textapi.classify({ url: req.body.text });
    res.end(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res
      .status(400)
      .end('This is not a valid text or article to evaluate. Try again.');
  }
});
```

Note that `res.send` and `res.end` are for sending text or bytes (Buffers). If you want to send JSON instead, express gives you a `res.json(...)` which is similar to `res.end(JSON.stringify(...))`.

Comment: Thanks for answering again Jacob, but It didn't work. This time it stopped the server from running.

Comment: Don't know maybe it's the client code it's wrong with? Or maybe the build tools?

Comment: Yes.  I'll post the error in an answer, since it's too long for a comment.

Comment: I see; that's just complaining that the response is an object. `res.send` and `res.end` require text or a buffer. If you want to send a JSON object, use `res.json()`.

Comment: So what I do is use res.json(response) instead of res.end(response)?

Comment: Yes, if you want the client to receive `response` as JSON.

Comment: Well the response from the aylien API is an object, and I want to send that object to client. I tried using res.json(response) instead of res.end(response) but It still doesn't work. This time no error in server terminal, but I still can't see the console log in inspect google chrome?

Comment: Do you have `console.log` messages on the server? Can you see if the `res.json(response)` call is being hit?

Comment: No error messages on the server when usin res.json(response). No i can't see that the res.json(response) is being hit (Dont know how to see). Last msg in the console is the console.log(response). It's the object that get's return from the Alyien API. So no error, just that. And in Chrome i expect that objectb eing sent since I use the res.json(response) but nothing :/ .. Thanks for taking your time Jacob btw, really appreciate it.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question with the latest version of your code; maybe I or someone else can spot the problem.

Comment: Done. I've edited the question with the "latest" code. If you want, I can put up the github link and you can see the whole thing. Since im really fresh at coding, it could be something maybr wrong with rest of the server js code, the webpack, or something else.

Comment: What is `textapi`? Is that a library we can look at docs for? Maybe `response` is not something that can be sent as JSON and you need to send a particular _property_ of `response`.

Comment: const aylien = require("aylien_textapi");
const textapi = new aylien({
    application_id: process.env.API_ID,
    application_key: process.env.API_KEY
});

Comment: And the the return is this:   {
  text: 'Trump Officials Are Said to Press Spies to Link Virus and Wuhan Labs\n' +
    'WASHINGTON — Senior Trump administration officials have pushed American spy agencies to hunt for evidence to supp ...William J. Broad and James Gorman contributed reporting from New York.',
  language: 'en',
  categories: [
    {
      label: 'defence - national security',
      code: '11001002',
      confidence: 0.11
    }
  ]
}

Comment: For your info, I just tried : res.json(response.categories) and it still didn't work.

Comment: Code you posted looks fine so far (except for one case where you aren't declaring a `data` variable, but that wouldn't explain the issue). It's gotta be something outside of the code posted thus far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212942/discussion-between-jacob-and-amir-heiwandi-abdulla).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the server.js file
It should be like this:

```
app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
console.log('I got a request.')
data = req.body;
console.log(data);
textapi.classify({
    url: data.text
}, function(error, response) {
    if (error === null) {
        console.log(response);
        res.send(response);
    } else {
        console.log('This is not a valid text or article to evaluate. Try again.')

    }
});
```

Comment: Don't know maybe it's the client code it's wrong with? Or maybe the build tools?